# How to close a tcp connection of the http request from self hosted owin server in .net 4.7?

Tags: owin, katana

I have a requirement to close a tcp connection from the server when a client sends a http request, so that the server can send the next http request with a new tcp connection. Could someone please help me how to do that?

I have tried throwing an exception in a middleware but the tcp connection is not closed as I can see the same connection being used in the next http request in Wireshark.

Comment: Are you trying to abort a connection without responding, or to close it after sending a response?

Comment: Anything would work for me but it would be better to close the connection after sending the response so that we could send headers with operationId/correlationId and customer could reach out to us with that if they want to.

Comment: You should be able to add a "Connection: close" header to the response to tell the client and server to close the connection after the response. I haven't tried this on HttpListener/Microsoft.Owin in a while, let me know how it works.

Comment: I have tried this and client closes the connection but then we are depending on the client implementation. This doesn't closes the connection from the server side and we want to close it from the server side.

Comment: That's a protocol compliant behavior that should be reliable. You should only go further if you consider the client to be malicious. Do you? The alternative is to call Abort. I'll dig up a sample.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httplistenerresponse.abort?view=netframework-4.8#System_Net_HttpListenerResponse_Abort
Something like `owinContext.Get<HttpListenerContext>().Response.Abort();`
This should only be done instead of sending a response, I don't think it's guaranteed to close the connection after the response is sent.